# wsimport pass no value to an enumerated parameter

Tags: soap, wsimport

I have a SOAP URL with one of the input parameters of enumerated type as below. With SOAPUI I'm just able to remove the `?` mark and able to execute the request successfully. `<urn:Comm_Source></urn:Comm_Source>`

I created client code using `wsimport` and it creates the input method parameter as `CommSourceType` object. If I pass null for this value the web service fails.

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Comm_Source" nillable="false" type="s0:Comm_SourceType"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of information for the complete answer (eg the whole wsdl/xsd or what means: *If I pass null for this value the web service fails.*).

In general:

1. `null` is not the same as an **empty string**.
2. `<urn:Comm_Source></urn:Comm_Source>` - is an **empty string**
3. `<urn:Comm_Source xsi:nil="true" />` - is a `null` value (`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`)
4. the specified element `<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Comm_Source" nillable="false" type="s0:Comm_SourceType" />` does not support `null` because there is `nillable="false"`.
5. The element can either be omitted or an **empty string** can be written in it.